# How should one use action in mobile app?

Tags: ember.js

Since in mobile app there is no click and there is a touchEnd event how i can use it easly with ember.js ? 
I know i can create a `Ember.View` with

```
events:
  touchEnd: ->
    console.log('my action')
```

I'm just searching for some more convenient way since creating a view for simple link in list is not the fastest way ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a touch gesture addon for ember called ember-touch. You can find it in https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-touch.

I hope it helps